# SQL query to get number of times a field repeats for another specific field

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Let's say I have two fields in a table. For the purpose of discussion let's say the fields are first name and last name. I want to know how many times the first name shows up listed next to the same last name. Assuming the last name column is unique, how do I figure out how many times each first name exists for each last name?

i.e. let's say I have a table with the following data:

```
Smith, John
Smith, David
Smith, Jane
Smith, John
Smith, John
Black, John
Black, Jane
Black, Jack
Black, Samantha
Black, Jack
```

I want a result that tells me that for Smith, there are 3 Johns, 1 David and 1 Jane, and for Black, there are 2 Jacks, 1 Jane and 1 Samantha.

Not sure how to format the output best. Maybe simply:

```
Smith, John, 3, David, 1, Jane, 1
Black, Jack, 2, Jane, 1, Samantha, 1
```

Something that would allow me to easily output something like:

```
Smith: John (3), David (1), Jane (1)
Black: Jack (2), Jane (1), Samantha (1)
```

It's important to note that it's possible that the second field can repeat, so counting unique instances in the column is not useful. It's only useful in reference to the first field.

Thanks.

Comment: _Columns_, not _fields_...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple aggregation?

```
select last_name, first_name, count(*)
from myTable
group by last_name, first_name
order by  last_name, first_name
```

Displaying it in a *Smith, John, 3, David, 1, Jane, 1* format will probably fail because there are way too many Smiths with way too many different last names.

Comment: This seems pretty good, but how do I get it to sort by the surname and then the count (not the first name). I had it working when I was messing around with the SQL but I lost it and now can't get it working again.

Comment: Actually I can get it to insert the count(*) in a count column:

    select last_name, first_name, count(*) cnt

and then:

    order by  last_name, cnt

although I need the cnt order to be in reverse (highest to lowest)

Comment: Got it, added ASC and DESC

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated sub-query in your `SELECT` statement and then wrap it all in a concat function to get the inline result you wanted

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        CONCAT(LastName, ': ', FirstName, '(', (SELECT COUNT(FirstName) FROM Person WHERE FirstName = p.FirstName AND LastName = p.LastName),')')
FROM    Person p
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
select name,surname, count(surname) over (partition by name) as cnt
from your_table
```

Comment: Must be MYSQL version 8 or above

Comment: I think it is not tagged

Comment: I like the simplicity of this but the database I'm using is not running MySQL 8 yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
SELECT CONCAT( Name,':', GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT( LastName, ' (', CNT , ')' ), ' ') ) 
FROM (
  SELECT Name, LastName, COUNT(*) CNT FROM MyTable
  GROUP BY 
  Name, LastName
 ) T 
 GROUP BY Name
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bff106/10/0)

Result:

```
Black:Jane (1) ,John (1) ,Samantha (1) ,Jack (2)
Smith:David (1) ,Jane (1) ,John (3)
```

Comment: I like the formatting and the link to SQL Fiddle (nice site), although I don't completely understand everything. How would you get it to sort the first names by the count (i.e. show in order of the highest count).